# Https Site viewed with Google Chrome on Windows 7 drops session

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, ssl, https

I have a custom e-commerce (codeigniter custom built site) that uses a cookie and db stored session data per visitor. If i use Google Chrome on windows 7, do some stuff that stores data in the session, then go away and come back to it 30 minutes later or something and it has dropped the session. The whole site is SSL secured if that helps.

Firefox and IE on win 7 don't do this, only Chrome and this doesn't happen on any other platform or browser.

My google fu has brought up nothing :(

Any ideas?

Comment: This is one of the answers posted on this forum that may bee useful to you:"Hey, I eventually found a solution. The issue was with how I configured Apache (htaccess file) to do URL Rewriting to hide my front controller in the URL.  I'm not sure if this is relevant to you, since you are probably on IIS...". http://forums.asp.net/t/1552666.aspx/1

Comment: Hmm, no, i don't think so. The problem is that the session seems to expire after a period of time. If you use the site without leaving it, it works fine, the session is maintained and all data is stored. So odd.

Comment: very odd! Good luck! I have read in some post that chrome will close session in some cases, like when server does not response to some request, or some handshake feels funny to him :). They say it is their way of handling messy web...